# What is the difference between areal density and attenuation coefficient?

Tags: photons, electrons, radiation, radioactivity, attenuation

Speaking of beta electrons, their attenuation is usually described by the areal density $\sigma$, i.e. "how much" g/cm^2 of a certain material they can pass through before stopping. I've read that, just like for photons, it is possible to calculate a linear attenuation coefficient $\mu$ that basically describes the rate of exponential decay in the intensity of the radiation. I have also learned that the mean free path is $1/\mu$. So does this mean that we could write a relation like $\sigma= (density) * (maximum$ $penetration$ $depth)= (density) * (mean$ $free$ $path) = density/\mu$, approximately?
Then what is stopping me from applying this same reasoning to photons and finding their areal density too? Why do we use two different parameters for beta and gamma rays, to describe the same thing?